# accing dynamic element through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to achieve this

```
$("div1 input").attr('id');
```

where div1 is dynamically generated through php loop ( so i have like div1,div2,div3 etc )

in my jquery function i have `$('#counter').val();`which holds calues from 1 to 3 dynamically,

so this is what i am doing `$("#div"+ $("#counter").val() +"input").attr('id')`

above code should give me input attribute id,

for some reasons or may be due to some syntax problem i am not getting it, **Have a look and point out my mistake** . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the space before `input`, try this:

```
$("#div" + $("#counter").val() + " input").attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your code, AFTER you are generated your divs. So you need to put `<script>` after loop generation or on document ready event.
Try following:

```
$(function()
{
        var $el = $("#div"+ $("#counter").val() +" input");
        //or you can use alert($el.length) to see if $el created.
        if ($el.length)
        {
           var id =  $el.attr('id');
        }

});
```